# Edit Skype's config.xml

Tags: c#, .net, file, acl, skype

I'm trying to edit Skype's `config.xml` file from code. It works fine, but after change Skype delete it and generate another one, undoing all my changes. For example, code:

```
public Core()
{
    try
    {
        var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Skype");
        if (processes.Length == 0)
        {
            AddRegistryKeys();
            RemovePlaceholder();
        }
        else
        {
            RestartSkypeAndRun(processes[0],
                () =>
                {
                    AddRegistryKeys();
                    RemovePlaceholder();
                });
        }
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} - {1}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
}

private static void RemovePlaceholder()
{
    string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    string skypePath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "Skype");
    foreach (var configPath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(skypePath, "config.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        string userConfig = File.ReadAllText(configPath);
        string fixedConfig = userConfig.Remove("<AdvertPlaceholder>1</AdvertPlaceholder>");
        File.Move(configPath, configPath + ".bak");
        File.WriteAllText(configPath, fixedConfig);
    }
}


private static void RestartSkypeAndRun(Process skypeProc, Action action)
{
    string skypeExePath = skypeProc.Modules[0].FileName;
    skypeProc.Kill();
    skypeProc.WaitForExit();
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)); //just in case

    action();

    Process.Start(skypeExePath);
}
```

So how can it be done? I have no idea, except blocking file modification, e.g. change ACL and other permissions for file, set readonly attribute e.t.c.

Comment: Is skype still running when you change the file?

Comment: No, see edit, i restart it if it's running

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/skype-hacks/0596101899/ch04s04.html

"Always stop Skype from running (by right-clicking on Skype in the system tray and choosing Quit) before making any changes to config.xml (or shared.xml), because even though your editor may tell you it has saved your updated version of config.xml, you may find that Skype ignores your changes and they are missing when you reopen config.xml. The procedure for editing any of Skype's configuration files should go like this: quit Skype (that is, stop it from running), edit (or delete) the configuration file, save the changes, and restart Skype."

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Application Data\Skype\Skypename\config.xml
```

"There is another file, shared.xml, from which Skype obtains configuration information that is common to all users of Skype on the same Windows machine... You also can edit this file to tweak how Skype behaves, but the scope for tweaking is far more limited than for config.xml. You typically can find shared.xml in these locations on each platform:

Windows (version 1.3 and before)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Skype\shared.xml
```

Windows (version 1.4 and after)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Application Data\Skype\shared.xml
```

"

Comment: I know, unfortunly, skype restart doesn't help, see edit

Comment: @Alex Just to be clear... you should stop skype... then edit config.xml ... then start skype... simply restarting then editing config.xml won't achieve anything.

Comment: Emm, I'm editing when skype is off, see `action()` between `Kill()` and `Start()`

Comment: Try a call to Close() to free up resources and handles, until the OS specifically frees resources it will keep handles and ExitTime in memory... btw are you 100% that Skype has actually exited correctly? i.e. can you see the process with an inspector? Try killing the process... then set a long wait... then go manually edit the config.xml... does that method lose your changes too?

Comment: Where should I call Close() ? I'm using static `File` class methods, so it handles all job with files. Anyway, I tried to create this file manually in temp folder and move it in skype folder. It creates a proper file in temp folder, but after copying the file gets corrupted (only root element w/o any child). I sure that skype is NOT closed properly, but it's fine because Kill() never terminates process correctly, but I'm also sure that Skype process dissapears from task manager's process list.